# Scope of variable outside 'if' loop in main method in a class - unavailable issue

Tags: java, variables

I want to store the value of Archers and Barbarians. However, outside the `if` statement I cannot get access to the `numberOfArchersToBeTrained` and `numberOfBarbariansToBeTrained` variables. What am I doing wrong here?

The last `System.out.println` is not working as the variable `numberOfArchersToBeTrained` is not available here

```
public class ConsoleInteraction {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a scanner so we can read the command-line input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Prompt for training or viewing camp
        System.out.print("What do you want to do: \n 1.Train Troops \n 2. View Troop Camp \n ");
        //Get the preference as an integer
        int preference = scanner.nextInt();

        int numberOfArchersToBeTrained;
        int numberOfBarbariansToBeTrained;

        //Show options based on preference
        if(preference == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Whom do you want to train?\n 1.Archer \n 2.Barbarian \n 3.Mix \n Enter You preference:");
            int trooppreference = scanner.nextInt();
            if (trooppreference == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("How many Archers you want to train ? : ");
                numberOfArchersToBeTrained = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            else if (trooppreference == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("How many Barbarians you want to train ? : ");
                numberOfBarbariansToBeTrained = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            else if (trooppreference == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("How many Archers you want to train ? :");
                numberOfArchersToBeTrained = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("How many Barbarians you want to train :");    
                numberOfBarbariansToBeTrained = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("You have to select option 1, 2 or 3");
            }
        }
        else if (preference == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Showing Camp to You");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("You can enter only option 1 or 2");
        }    

        System.out.println("Archers:"+ numberOfArchersToBeTrained);

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message you're seeing? Is it saying that it can't find the symbol, or that it's not initialized?

Comment: `if` is not a loop of any kind.

Comment: sorry, I meant if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if prefence is either 2 or 3, **numberOfArchersToBeTrained** is not initialized, you need to give this variable value

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just wondering( I am a beginner). If I do not initialize then doesn't it get initialized to a default value ? Asking this because , I am anyway manipulating the variable inside the if block, and if compiler had to complain( about no initialization) why didn't it complain inside the if block when I was assigning values to it? Apologies if it is a  bit of a stupid query

Comment: it is much better if you initialize, but you can find more information here : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `numberOfArchersToBeTrained` at the beginning, your code is working;

```
 int numberOfArchersToBeTrained = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Semih. Working now. Have a followup doubt which I have posted in the post above